# Group the objects based on object key and value

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

My present objects

```
{
   {
     "_id": "5ff3e51c8bb6cc1e564075c3",
        "user_id": "210105093340",
        "account_status": "Active",
        "profile_pic": "1609837105.891015.jpeg",
        "cd": "2021-01-05 09:33:40",
        "compare_date": "2021-01-05",
        "date": "January 06, 2021"
        "type": "Public",

    },
    {
        "_id": "5ff3e51c8bb6cc1e564075c3",
        "user_id": "210105093340",
        "account_status": "Active",
        "profile_pic": "1609837105.891015.jpeg",
        "cd": "2021-01-05 09:33:40",
        "compare_date": "2021-01-05",
        "date": "January 06, 2021"
        "type": "Private"

    },
    {
        "_id": "5ff3e51c8bb6cc1e564075c3",
        "user_id": "210105093340",
        "account_status": "Active",
        "profile_pic": "1609837105.891015.jpeg",
        "cd": "2021-01-05 09:33:40",
        "compare_date": "2021-01-06",
        "date": "January 06, 2021",
        "type": "Private"

    },
    {
        "_id": "5ff3e51c8bb6cc1e564075c3",
        "user_id": "210105093340",
        "account_status": "Active",
        "profile_pic": "1609837105.891015.jpeg",
        "cd": "2021-01-05 09:33:40",
        "compare_date": "2021-01-06",
        "date": "January 06, 2021"
         "type": "Public"

    }
   
}
```

I want the grouped object like

```
{

date:2021-01-05,
public:{
 {"_id": "5ff3e51c8bb6cc1e564075c3",
            "user_id": "210105093340",
            "account_status": "Active",
            "compare_date": "2021-01-06",
            "date": "January 06, 2021"
            "type": "Public",
},
 "_id": "5ff3e51c8bb6cc1e564075c3",
            "user_id": "210105093340",
            "account_status": "Active",
            "compare_date": "2021-01-06",
            "date": "January 06, 2021"
            "type": "Public",


},
    
Private:{

   {
            "_id": "5ff3e51c8bb6cc1e564075c3",
            "user_id": "210105093340",
            "account_status": "Active",
            "compare_date": "2021-01-06",
            "date": "January 06, 2021",
            "type": "Private"

        },
        {
            "_id": "5ff3e51c8bb6cc1e564075c3",
            "user_id": "210105093340",
            "account_status": "Active",
            "compare_date": "2021-01-06",
            "date": "January 06, 2021",
            "type": "Private"

        },


}

},
{

date:2021-01-05,
public:{
 {"_id": "5ff3e51c8bb6cc1e564075c3",
            "user_id": "210105093340",
            "account_status": "Active",
            "compare_date": "2021-01-05",
            "date": "January 05, 2021"
            "type": "Public",
},
 "_id": "5ff3e51c8bb6cc1e564075c3",
            "user_id": "210105093340",
            "account_status": "Active",
            "compare_date": "2021-01-05",
            "date": "January 05, 2021"
            "type": "Public",


},
    
Private:{

      {
            "_id": "5ff3e51c8bb6cc1e564075c3",
            "user_id": "210105093340",
            "account_status": "Active",
            "compare_date": "2021-01-05",
            "date": "January 05, 2021",
            "type": "Private"

        },
        {
            "_id": "5ff3e51c8bb6cc1e564075c3",
            "user_id": "210105093340",
            "account_status": "Active",
            "compare_date": "2021-01-0",
            "date": "January 05, 2021",
            "type": "Private"

        },


}


}
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried? This site is not a code-writing service, you are supposed to show us your attempt at least.

Comment: are you using laravel or codeigniter, i would imagine it isn't both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the input data you provided is not valid JSON. There were commas missing or at the wrong place and the outer curly brackets should have been square ones. Here is a "corrected" version and a way to produce the output you desired as "closely as possible":

```
$in='[
   {
        "_id": "5ff3e51c8bb6cc1e564075c3",
        "user_id": "210105093340",
        "account_status": "Active",
        "profile_pic": "1609837105.891015.jpeg",
        "cd": "2021-01-04 09:33:40",
        "compare_date": "2021-01-05",
        "date": "January 06, 2021",
        "type": "Public"

    },
    {
        "_id": "5ff3e51c8bb6cc1e564075c3",
        "user_id": "210105093340",
        "account_status": "Active",
        "profile_pic": "1609837105.891015.jpeg",
        "cd": "2021-01-05 09:33:40",
        "compare_date": "2021-01-05",
        "date": "January 06, 2021",
        "type": "Private"

    },
    {
        "_id": "5ff3e51c8bb6cc1e564075c3",
        "user_id": "210105093340",
        "account_status": "Active",
        "profile_pic": "1609837105.891015.jpeg",
        "cd": "2021-01-05 09:33:40",
        "compare_date": "2021-01-06",
        "date": "January 06, 2021",
        "type": "Private"

    },
    {
        "_id": "5ff3e51c8bb6cc1e564075c3",
        "user_id": "210105093340",
        "account_status": "Active",
        "profile_pic": "1609837105.891015.jpeg",
        "cd": "2021-01-05 09:33:40",
        "compare_date": "2021-01-06",
        "date": "January 06, 2021",
         "type": "Public"

    }
   
]';

$out=array_reduce(json_decode($in), function($a,$c){
  $a[substr($c->cd,0,10)][$c->type][]=[
      "_id"=>$c->_id,
      "user_id"=>$c->user_id,
      "account_status"=>$c->account_status,
      "compare_date"=>$c->compare_date,
      "date"=>$c->date,
      "type"=>$c->type ];
   return $a;}, [] );

  array_walk($out,function($arr,$key) use(&$res) { 
    $arr['Date']=$key;
    array_walk($arr, function($ar,$k) use($key,&$res) {
      $res[$key][$k]=$ar;
    });
  });
  foreach ($res as $el) $result[]=$el;
    
  print_r($result);
```

You can find a working demo here: https://rextester.com/BQWU57249

This is the output:

```
array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Public] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [_id] => 5ff3e51c8bb6cc1e564075c3
                            [user_id] => 210105093340
                            [account_status] => Active
                            [compare_date] => 2021-01-05
                            [date] => January 06, 2021
                            [type] => Public
                        )
                )
            [Date] => 2021-01-04
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [Private] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [_id] => 5ff3e51c8bb6cc1e564075c3
                            [user_id] => 210105093340
                            [account_status] => Active
                            [compare_date] => 2021-01-05
                            [date] => January 06, 2021
                            [type] => Private
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [_id] => 5ff3e51c8bb6cc1e564075c3
                            [user_id] => 210105093340
                            [account_status] => Active
                            [compare_date] => 2021-01-06
                            [date] => January 06, 2021
                            [type] => Private
                        )
                )
            [Public] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [_id] => 5ff3e51c8bb6cc1e564075c3
                            [user_id] => 210105093340
                            [account_status] => Active
                            [compare_date] => 2021-01-06
                            [date] => January 06, 2021
                            [type] => Public
                        )
                )
            [Date] => 2021-01-05
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want them grouped by date, and then further by the type of the account, you could do something like this.

A relatively simple foreach loop should do the trick, considering you have transformed your json into a array of arrays.

```
    $filteredAccounts = [];

    foreach ($accounts as $account) {
        $date = new \DateTime($account['date']);

        $filteredAccounts[$date->format('Y-m-d')][$account['type']][] = $account;
    }

    // Then you build your final array you want.

    $groupedAccounts = [];

    foreach ($filteredAccounts as $date => $filteredAccount) {
        $filteredAccount['Date'] = $date;

        $groupedAccounts[] = $filteredAccount;
    }

    var_dump($groupedAccounts);
```

But as others have mentioned your question doesn't really have anything to do with Laravel, but regardless this should help you along the way if you wanted it in a raw way.

Comment: Thankyou Mikkel Schov. i will check and update you.